# knitr chapter bibliographies from .Rnw files?

Tags: knitr, bibliography, biblatex

One can create chapter bibliographies using BibLaTeX and straight .tex files, as shown in this MWE:

```
% main.tex
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{chapterbib}

\begin{document}

\include{chap1}
\include{chap2}

\end{document}


% chap1.tex
\chapter{one chapter}

text~\cite{paper1}
text~\cite{paper2}

\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\bibliography{biblio}


% chap2.tex
\chapter{another chapter}

text~\cite{paper2, paper3}

\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\bibliography{biblio}


% biblio.bib
@Article{paper1,
  author =       {John Smith},
  title =        {A title},
  journal =      {A Journal},
  year =         {2010}
}
@Article{paper2,
  author =       {John Doe},
  title =        {A paper},
  journal =      {Another journal},
  year =         {2009}
}
@Article{paper3,
  author =       {Yuppie Networking},
  title =        {My paper},
  journal =      {The best journal},
  year =         {2000}
}
```

The above files can be successfully compiled with the following script:

```
% compile.bash
#!/bin/bash
pdflatex main.tex
for auxfile in chap*.aux
do
    bibtex `basename $auxfile .aux`
done
pdflatex main.tex
pdflatex main.tex
```

I wish to re-create the above functionality using knitr, BibLaTeX, and .Rnw files (not .tex files).  Here's a small non-working example.  (I know this example lacks R code chunks, but my use case will have R code chunks.)

```
% main.Rnw
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{chapterbib}

\begin{document}

\Sexpr{knitr::knit_child("chap1.Rnw")}
\Sexpr{knitr::knit_child("chap2.Rnw")}

\end{document}


% chap1.Rnw
\chapter{one chapter}

text~\cite{paper1}
text~\cite{paper2}

\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\bibliography{biblio}


% chap2.Rnw
\chapter{another chapter}

text~\cite{paper2, paper3}

\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\bibliography{biblio}


% knit_script.R
knitr::knit(input = "main.Rnw")


% compileRnw.bash
/usr/local/bin/Rscript knit_script.R

pdflatex main.tex
for auxfile in chap*.aux
do
    bibtex `basename $auxfile .aux`
done
pdflatex main.tex
pdflatex main.tex
```

When I run the `compileRnw.bash` script, the resulting document lacks bibliographies.

What should `main.Rnw` and `compileRnw.bash` look like to create a document with chapter bibliographies from the .Rnw files?

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for this response!

A point of clarification.

- In the examples, I use

```
\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\bibliography{biblio}
```

in every chapter file, because I want a bibliography at the end of every chapter.
To be specific, I want 2 bibliographies, one after Chapter 1 (containing only references from Chapter 1)
and another after Chapter 2 (containing only references from Chapter 2).

- Thanks to the answer from Yihui,
  I found that the following changes produce the output that I want.

In `main.Rnw`:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{chapterbib}

\begin{document}

% \Sexpr{knitr::knit_child("chap1.Rnw")}
% \Sexpr{knitr::knit_child("chap2.Rnw")}

\include{chap1}
\include{chap2}

\end{document}
```

In `knit_script.R`:

```
# knit_script.R

# knitr::knit(input = "main.Rnw")

knitr::knit(input = "chap1.Rnw")
knitr::knit(input = "chap2.Rnw")
knitr::knit(input = "main.Rnw")
```

With those changes, I obtain a bibliography for each chapter.

Answer (score 0):

`\Sexpr{knitr::knit_child("chap1.Rnw")}` knits `chap1.Rnw` and returns the text content of `chap1.tex` instead of `\include{chap1}`. That's the difference between using `.Rnw` (your non-working example) and plain `.tex` (your first working example), which means there will not be a `chap1.aux`, because there is one and only one `.tex` output file, which is `main.tex`. You will only get one `.aux` file, too, which is `main.aux`. Then you need to run `bibtex` on `main.aux` instead of `chap*.aux`. Your shell script should be:

```
pdflatex main.tex
bibtex main.aux
pdflatex main.tex
pdflatex main.tex
```

In fact, you do not really need this shell script, because `knitr::knit2pdf('main.Rnw')` does all these steps automatically. Or equivalently, you can click the button "Compile PDF" on the RStudio toolbar if you use RStudio.

BTW, I don't know why you had to declare

```
\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\bibliography{biblio}
```

in each chapter. That seems to be unnecessary. You can declare the bib style and database once in `main.Rnw`. If you duplicate them in each chapter, `bibtex` will complain, although it doesn't really hurt.